# Inject viewModel with hilt

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, dagger-2, dagger-hilt, recyclerlistview

I want to inject my viewModel inside RecyclerView with Hilt.
It can be inject but viewModel not destroy when recyclerView destroyed.
what is the best way to inject viewModel inside recyclerView with hilt?

Comment: Are you trying to inject ViewModel into the recycler view adapter?
If yes, what is the use case scenario?

Comment: Yes I want add viewModel inside RecyclerView Adapter.
In my case I want each recyclerView Adapter has own viewModel 
so we can observe viewModel objects in fragments

Comment: Ideally, it should not be the case. Please explain your use case.

Comment: for example we want detect on row click inside fragment
but our recyclerViewAdapter reuse multi places in application

Comment: A Viewmodel should not be injected into the adapter. Whatever you are trying to achieve, there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: what is your solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create separate adapter and viewholder classes and then you can inject your viewModel inside that viewholder class instead of the adapter.
To destroy the viewModel you should manually do it by observing the parentlifecycle. when the parent lifecycle event is ON_DESTROY do something similar to this in the init block of the adapter class.

```
parentLifecycle.addObserver(object : LifecycleObserver {

            @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
            fun onParentDestroy() {
                recyclerView?.run {
                    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
                        getChildAt(i)?.let {
                            (getChildViewHolder(it) as BaseItemViewHolder<*, *>)
                                .run {
                                    onDestroy()
                                    viewModel.onManualCleared()
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
  }
```

Here `onManualCleared()` function calls `onCleared()`.

Answer (score 0):

A view model shouldn't be injected inside an adapter, as I read in the comments you can you a better way than that,
Let's imagine you have an adapter with many rows, each row when the user clicks on it, it performs a network call.
First, create an `interface`

```
interface Click {
fun onClick(index: Int, item: Model)
}
```

inside your adapter, init an instance of it then use it in your `onBindViewHolder`

```
yourview.setOnClickListener {v-> interface.onClick()}
```

don't forget to init the interface whether the place you're using it (Activity/Fragment/...).
This is a better solution than using a ViewModel for every row, which may lead to a SystemLeaks.